# After re-building the amplify project, the existing cognito was deleted and replaced with a new one

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I had two amplify projects, one created with a cognito that I used in another application and another amplify project that I created by hosting from a github repository that also had its own cognito.
Then I wanted to create the web host but in the first amplify project, in order to have that front project with the cognito of the other project. When the build was done automatically, the cognito that it had with users was deleted and a new one was created. What could this have been due to?

I contacted support to be able to recover the cognito but they told me that it is not possible and that they could not help me with those technical questions so I do not know what could have caused the error.